# Shouting/ shouted with happiness, William celebrated his chance to interview

Tags: past-participles, present-participles

As I was studying on participles I came across the following sentence.

> *Shouting* with happiness, William celebrated his chance to interview at SunTrust.

I know the participle phrase in the sentence modifies the William so the sentence is grammatically correct and what I understand from the sentence is that William shouted with happiness (first) and then celebrated his chance to interview.But even though he shouted first , I think, celebration and shouting may overlaps in terms of time also.But I am not certain about it.

My question is that what would the sentence imply if I changed present participles with past participles as the following:

> *Shouted* with happiness, William celebrated his chance to interview at
>   SunTrust.

Would it change the order of the actions or interval between the actions or stress on them?

Comment: It would not make sense and would not be ungrammatical in English. Shouting with happiness implies the action was ongoing when he celebrated. If you want a single action with shouting, you would have to do something like this: William shouted with happiness when etc.

Comment: I would say that the 'shouting' and the 'celebrating' were co-occurring. Supplementary adjuncts like this are usually gerund-participials, so you can't change it to "shouted".

Comment: There is no ing co-occurrence.

Comment: @Lambie The salient interpretation is that the shouting was part of his celebrations. I'd call that co-occurring.

Comment: Ok, let's try some others: Laughing out loud, he jumped into the pool. He was laughing out loud while he jumped into the pool. But that does not automatically mean he was laughing and jumping does it? During the past act of jumping, he was laughing. He was laughing when he jumped into the pool.....:)

Comment: @Lambie Does the second sentence sound like someone made William laughed while he was celebrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present participle in the original sentence does mean that the action of *shouting* overlaps or occurs at the same time as *celebrated*. The first sentence does **not** mean that William shouted first and then he celebrated. If you want to say that you use the past participle:

> Having shouted with happiness, William celebrated his chance...

The version you suggest, namely

> Shouted with happiness, William celebrated his chance...

makes little sense. The way I would interpret that is that the past participle acts like a passive construction, and thus William *was "shouted with happiness"  by some agent*, and that makes no sense at all.

A version that works is

> Filled with happiness, William celebrated his chance...

which is short for

> Being filled happiness...